# How to save a WorkSheet from an Excel spreadsheet as a PDF

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, excel-2016

I'm trying to write (what I thought would be) a simple macro which will save a Worksheet (not the whole Workbook) from an Excel Spreadsheet as a PDF. I'm using Excel 2016 (15.24) on a MacBook Pro running Yosemite. I've seen lots of examples here and online.

I started out by recording a macro and edited it. It looked like this:

```
Sub SavePDF()
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "pdfs/excelsheetstopdf.pdf", FileFormat:=xlPDF, _
    PublishOption:=xlSheet
End Sub
```

This produced a PDF file but it contained all of the sheets from the Workbook. It seems that, for some reason, the PublishOption:=xlSheet although it works manually when recording the macro, does not work from VBA.

Ok. So I tried a different approach using ExportAsFixedFormat, modelling my approach on some of the examples I've seen here and elsewhere online and trying to keep it as simple as possible. Here's my version.

```
Sub SimplePDF()
   ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
      Type:=xlTypePDF, _
      Filename:="pdfs/example.pdf", _
      Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
      IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
      IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
      OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```

Every time I try this I get a print error, followed by the dreaded run-time error 1004. BTW, does anyone know the definition of this error?

Can anyone suggest why this is not working? I'd be grateful for any advice.

On the strength of Sinan's advice below I changed the code to

```
Sub SavePDF()
   ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:= _
   "pdfs/excelsheetstopdf.pdf", FileFormat:=xlPDF
End Sub
```

I get the same run-time error 1004 but it gives me the extra information "SaveAs method of Worksheet class failed"

I tried David Zemens technique below of copying the active worksheet to a new Workbook and then using SaveAs on that new workbook.

```
Sub NSavePDF()
    ActiveSheet.Copy

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "pdfs/excelsheetstopdf.pdf", FileFormat:=xlPDF, _
        PublishOption:=xlSheet

    'Close the new workbook without saving it.
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

End Sub
```

However, this attempts to print the worksheet on my default printer rather than converting to PDF.

Comment: What's the "print error"?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking to save the entire workbook and that is what is happening. Instead, you can figure out which *worksheet* you want to save as PDF, and invoke `SaveAs` method on that.

See [Worksheet.SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195820.aspx) instead of `Workbook.SaveAs`.

> Saves changes to the chart or worksheet in a different file.
>
> #### Syntax
>
> `expression.SaveAs(FileName, FileFormat, Password, WriteResPassword, ReadOnlyRecommended, CreateBackup, AddToMru, TextCodepage, TextVisualLayout, Local)`
>
> `expression`: A variable that represents a Worksheet object.

```
Sub SaveSheetAsPDF()
ActiveWorksheet.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "pdfs/excelsheetstopdf.pdf", FileFormat:=xlPDF
End Sub
```

If some reason that doesn't work (but `Workbook.SaveAs` does), you could simply copy the sheet to a new workbook containing only one sheet, and then do `SaveAs` on that workbook.

```
Sub SavePDF()
    ActiveSheet.Copy '## This creates a new workbook containing only the copied sheet
    'ActiveWorkbook should now be the new/copied worksheet:

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "pdfs/excelsheetstopdf.pdf", FileFormat:=xlPDF, _
        PublishOption:=xlSheet
    'Close the new workbook without saving it.
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: @DavidZemens Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers guys, but neither approach works for me. I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: This is so annoying. It seems to work fine on the PC version of Excel but not on my version of Excel for Mac (now 16.10).